# Getting SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error but query is performed anyway

Tags: php, mysql

I'm making a system to save users' IPs into a table along with the last time they posted something.
First, I check for an already-existent record of the user's IP with

```
SELECT lastpost FROM  users WHERE ip = '$IP'
```

I then check whether the result of that query is empty, and if it is it means that the user's IP is not present and it should be recorded, so I proceed by doing this query:

```
INSERT INTO users (ip, lastpost) VALUES ('$IP', '$ctime')
```

Where `$IP` is the user's IP fetched using `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` and `$ctime` is a time string created `using date("Y-m-j H:i:s")`.
Even though after performing the latter query the data is present into the table, I keep getting the error

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error
```

Which is, by itself, not very helpful. I'd like to understand what I'm doing wrong here. Thanks in advance.

**P.S.:** I'll use this question to also ask how I could compare, using a query, the time I have calculated with PHP's `date()` with the time already present in the table (of type "datetime") to see if the one calculated with `date()` is greater than the one in the database by at least one minute.

Comment: Check the event log on the server.

Comment: I'm having trouble finding it, where's it located? (I'm using XAMPP)

Comment: The log file should be located at D:/xampp/mysql/data/mysql.log, but it's not present at all in that folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first try to cast `$ctime` as a datetime `CAST('$ctime' AS DATETIME)` to see if that works.

For testing minute difference use `TIMEDIFF()`.

```
SELECT IF(TIMEDIFF(CAST('$ctime' AS DATETIME), lastpost) > CAST('00:01:00.000000' AS DATETIME), /*do this*/, /*else do this*/)
```

This will return a time difference. If the time difference is negative, `$ctime` is earlier than lastpost. But you can get into pretty fine granularity here.

See if the above helps.

(Oh, I found all of this via Google and searching for mysql and datediff, timediff, or cast.)